# Same version of PhantomJS has different results on Mac OsX and Ubuntu?

Tags: python, macos, selenium, phantomjs, ubuntu-14.04

Apologies if this is not the right place to post this.

I am using a script to scrape asynchronously loaded content from news sites and am running into a situation where the version of phantomJS (with selenium on python) that I have running on my dev machine (a mac with El Capitan) has a much higher level of success than the version I am running on an ubuntu 14.04 LTS server. Despite the fact that I am using the exact same version of Python (3.6.0), Selenium library for python (3.4.0), ghostdriver (1.2.0, but I believe this is just what comes with Selenium) and PhantomJS (2.1.1).

I am running PhantomJS in both places with the following options: 
`--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--debug=true', '--load-images=false'`

I generally had an issue where the driver was getting the pages, but not able to find the target content because it might not have been letting the page long enough to load all the content. If I add a basic sleep in there between `driver.get()` and when I parse the page with beautiful soup (also same version - 4.5.3), it solves the problem in the mac environment. Though on the ubuntu environment, no matter how long it sleeps, it appears not to be loading all of the asynchronous content and then tends to fail to scrape on those pages.

I'd say on the mac environment it's getting nearly 100% of the content it is looking to scrape, where as on the ubuntu environment it is only getting roughly 50% consistently. So it is working, just not as reliably.

Is there a reason why the exact same version of PhantomJS would perform much more inconsistently where really the only difference is the operating system they are running on? Is there a good way to figure out why phantomjs is failing? The ghostdriver logs in debug mode don't really seem to be telling me anything useful regarding this issue.